# bubble chat weight in python and pyQT

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I'm developing a chat application where the user chats with a program.
What I'm working on now is simulating the bubbles in sms programs، So far this what I have done:

```
 from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui,QtWidgets
 import sys

class Bubble(QtWidgets.QLabel):
  def __init__(self,text):
    super(Bubble,self).__init__(text)
    self.setContentsMargins(5,5,5,5)

  def paintEvent(self, e):

    p = QtGui.QPainter(self)
    p.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing,True)
    p.drawRoundedRect(0,0,self.width()-1,self.height()-1,5,5)

    super(Bubble,self).paintEvent(e)

 class MyWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):

   def __init__(self,text,left=True):
      super(MyWidget,self).__init__()
      hbox = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
      label = Bubble(text)
      if left is not True:      
         hbox.addSpacerItem(QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(1,1,
           QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding,QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred))
         hbox.addWidget(label)
    if left is True:
         hbox.addSpacerItem(QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(1,1,
           QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding,QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred))

    hbox.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
    self.setLayout(hbox)
    self.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
   w = QtWidgets.QWidget()
   vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
   vbox.addWidget(MyWidget("Left side"))
   vbox.addWidget(MyWidget("Right side",left=False))
   w.setLayout(vbox)
   w.show()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This code is working, but I want is to add a `QPushButton`, a `QLineEdit`, and a `QTextBrowser`. So when the user writes something and clicks the button, a bubble will be holding the text written by the user.

Does anybody have any ideas to help me?

Comment: Sorry, no idea. The question is too difficult to understand. What does "a bubble will be from holding the text" mean and how should that look like?

Comment: Look into `QScrollArea`.  You probably want to place all the Bubble `QLabels` inside a widget inside a `QScrollArea`.  That way, the widget keeps getting longer (more bubbles), but it's wrapped in a scrollable area, so you can scroll to see all portions of the widget.